# Let $T$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. Find a function $g$ such that $g(T)$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> **Question**: Let $T$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. Find a function $g$ such that $g(T)$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$.

I used the density mapping theorem for single variable.
What I get after solving a differential equation is:
$$g(t)=C-e^{-\lambda t},$$
for some constant C. But I'm having trouble restricting the range of $g$ to be $[0,1]$. Can I just let $C=1$, so that $g$ is between $[0,1)?$ But now $1$ is not in the interval.
May I know what can I do?

Work:

Let $U=g(T)$. We want $g$ such that $$\bigg\rvert\frac{dg^{-1}(u)}{du}\bigg\rvert \lambda e^{-\lambda g^{-1}(u)}=1.$$
Solving this equation gives $g^{-1}(u)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln\left(\frac{1}{C-u}\right)$.

Comment: Check your calculations again. The correct answer is $g(t)=e^{-\lambda t}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I think both give similar answer. Just different endpoints are not included in different cases.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy When solving the differential equation, I ambiguously suppose the derivative is positive. If I take negative, then your answer will be obtained.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why can't? A bounded increasing function can do the job.

Comment: #bounded by above

Comment: If you take the derivative to be positive you do not get a valid answer . You have already observed difficulties in this case. So take negative value for the derivative and you get  valid answer. Anyway are expected to find one function $g$ such that $g(T)$ is unifromly distributed, not all such functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an immediate example of [integral transform theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20the%20probability,having%20a%20standard%20uniform%20distribution.) thus the result is the CDF of $Y$

$$G=1-e^{-\lambda T}$$

You can verify this solution

$$\mathbb{P}(G\leq g)=\mathbb{P}(1-e^{-\lambda T}\leq g)=\dots=\mathbb{P}\left(T\leq -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log(1-g)\right)=$$

$$ =F_T \left( -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log(1-g)\right)=1-e^{-\lambda(-1/\lambda)\log(1-g)}=g $$

Comment: So the endpoint is not a big deal?

Comment: @123 : added a full verification of my result

Comment: Understood. Thank you.